# Calling webservice with array params using resttemplate

Tags: java, spring, curl, resttemplate, query-string

How can i call the below webservice using resttemplate

curl -v POST --cert kkk.cer --key kkk.private --pass kkk --cacert sslservercachain.cer "https://hello-sign.api-dev.myname.com/v1/gkscl/1p1/services/filesLocation" -H "Authorization: Bearer zxAM4M90964ae" -d "{\"fileids\" : [1, 21, 22]}"

Comment: What does web service expects exactly? Is there any request contract?

Comment: it is a post request.It expects a result in json format

Comment: Of course. But what is the correct format which is server accepts?

Comment: you mean the format of the parameters?It should be an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I assume that server has some controller like (you can adjust the difference pieces to work for you it is just an example) :

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity somePost(@RequestBody PostRequestObject request)
{
    // logic
}
```

Create a corresponding class for send request:

```
@Data
class PostRequestObject { 
    List<Integer> data;
}
```

Send request with resttemplate:

```
PostRequestObject request = new PostRequestObject();
request.setData(Arrays.asList(1,21,22));
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + "zxAM4M90964ae");
HttpEntity<Object> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(request, headers);

     ResponseEntity<YourResponseClass> result = restTemplate.exchange(
                "https://hello-sign.api-dev.myname.com/v1/gkscl/1p1/services/filesLocation",
                HttpMethod.POST,
                requestEntity,
                YourResponseClass.class);
```

Try this after -d :

```
 'fields[]=1&fields[]=21&fields[]=22'
```

Comment: I want to execute the above in Java.Preferable using a resttemplate